# What is this white rhombus icon on the mini map in Enter the Gungeon?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

In Enter the Gungeon, this white distorted rectangle icon appeared after I cleared a room in floor 1:

[image: Mini map icon]

The room looks empty and the icon on the mini map seems to correspond to the walls in the center:

[image: Full game screenshot]

So what does this icon mean?

Comment: I haven't played the game, but the white rhombus on the minimap looks like it's just the staircase-shaped wall in the middle of the room, isn't it? Otherwise, I'm not sure which rhombus you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is just the walls. I got a similar room on another run and was able to verify it.